# How to make a REST API call inside subscribe method of a Mono<T>

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming

I have a Spring boot application with Spring WebFlux. I want to call a API Rest in a non blocking way and after that, inside subscribe method, call another API Rest.

The first call executes correct and the subscribe method too. My problem is that inside the subscribe, how can I request another API Rest?

```java
@Autowired
WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

Mono<UserRating> monoUserRating = webClientBuilder.build().get().uri("http://ratings-data-service:8083/ratingsdata/user/" + userId)             .retrieve().bodyToMono(UserRating.class);

monoUserRating.subscribe(CatalogResource::handleResponseUserRating);

private static List<CatalogItem> handleResponseUserRating(UserRating userRating) {
    System.out.println("How to call another API???");

    //this doesn't work since is not static
    Movie movie = webClientBuilder.build().get().uri("http://movie-info-service:8082/movies/"+ rating.getMovieId())
                        .retrieve().bodyToMono(Movie.class).block();

}
```

Comment: use `flatMap` which helps to subscribe to inner Mono automatically. I would suggest like instead of using `block()`change the method return type to `Flux<CatalogItem>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Mono.flatMap` to bind two async operations together, [link to doc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-).

```
@Autowired
WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

public void main() {
  Mono<Movie> movieMono = getUserRating(userId)
    .flatMap(userRating -> handlerUserRating(userRating));
  movieMono.subscribe(movie -> handleMovie(movie));
}

private Mono<UserRating> getUserRating(String userId) {
  return webClientBuilder.build()
    .get()
    .uri("http://ratings-data-service:8083/ratingsdata/user/" + userId)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(UserRating.class);
}

private Mono<Movie> handleUserRating(UserRating rating) {
  return webClientBuilder.build()
    .get()
    .uri("http://movie-info-service:8082/movies/"+ rating.getMovieId())
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(Movie.class);
}
```